# @CrossOrigin not working with POST method

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring

Hello I`m developing a web app. Backend is running with Spring and frontend with React. I have problem with CrossOrigin if I am using POST Http method.
Here is my js code:

```
const LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost:8080/auth/login";

login(username, password) {
return axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
  username,
  password,
});
```

}

**Here I am getting an error:**

- Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/auth/login due to access control checks.
- Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**Java Spring sample code:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")

public class AuthController {

 ...

@PostMapping("/login") 

public ResponseEntity<?> signInUser(@RequestBody LoginBody loginBody){

.....

 return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");

}
```

**But if I use GET request, like this:**

JS Code:

```
  hello() {
return axios.get(HELLO_URL);}
```

Java Code:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("public")
public class HelloWorld {

@GetMapping("/hello")
public String helloWorld() {return "Hello ";}

}
```

**I dont have errors. Everything works fine**

Do you have any idea how fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add @CrossOrigin on top of your @PostMapping("/login") annotaion instead of using at the class level.